# FieldStorageConfigStorage::loadByProperties() with multiple conditions doesn't return any result

Tags: webforms, 9

Using FieldStorageConfigStorage::loadByProperties() with the entity_type and sid (from webforms) as conditions doesn't return any results. I can get a result if I run each of the conditions separately. Could be related to this issue, but I am not sure: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2917606. How can I fix this issue? If I need to write a repository service for this how do I do that?

My current code is the following one.

```php
$storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform_submission');
$webform_submission = $storage->loadByProperties([
  'entity_type' => 'node',
  'sid' => $survey->get('field_webform_submission_id')->getString(),
]);
```

I am using Drupal 9.4.1 on PHP 8, using MySQL as database.

Comment: What is `$storage` set to?

Comment: I added it to the original post:                     
$storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform_submission');

Comment: Try `$survey->get('field_webform_submission_id')->value`.

Comment: `webform_submission` is a content entity. BTW, if you have the ID you don't need to query, you can just load the entity: `$storage->load($sid)`

Comment: As a side note, the storage class for *webform_submission* entities cannot load a different entity like a node. The shown code won't work.

Comment: I tried that, but then getData(); doesn't get any data from $webform_submission.

Comment: With ```$storage->load($sid)``` I ran into issues, but ```$survey->get('field_webform_submission_id')->value``` worked for me.

Comment: The second command gets the `$sid` you need for the first command. The problem is, your question asking about the field storage has nothing to do with either and it's unclear what you are asking about. So I'm voting to close the question.